# Cache control in header not working in safari with rails3

Tags: caching, safari, cache-control

I am building an application in rails3. And i want to prevent cache in my application.
I added the following code in my application controller:

before_filter :set_cache_buster

```
 def set_cache_buster
     response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
  end
```

It works fine with firefox,chrome.But it is not working with safari.

I also tried

```
body onunload=""
```

in my application.html but still not get success.

Anyone knows how to prevent cache in safari? Please help.